# Append 2 separate return values of one function to 2 separate lists in a for loop in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, append, multiple-return-values

I have a function that returns 2 lists separately, in principle like this:

```
def function_returns_two(many_args**):
    do_something_fancy
    return list1, list2
```

This function returns a different *list1* each time you call it, because there is some random picking of rows from a pandas dataframe involved, while *list2* is always the same. — Now I want to iterate this function, in principle:

```
for i in range(10):
    data, labl = function_returns_two(many_args**)
```

But obviously that won't work as needed, because for every iteration *list1* and *list2* get **assigned** to the same variable (*data*, *labl*), that is the previously assigned values get replaced.

Instead, I want to append them. — But how? Is it even possible?

```
for i in range(10):
    (data, labl).append(function_returns_two(many_args**)) # ???
```

How would you solve this?

---

*PS: Im already using this function for another task, and I'd like to reuse it here. Of course, if what I want is not possible, I can still build a separate function.*

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
data = []
lable = []
for i in range(10):
    d, l = function_returns_two(many_args**)
    data.append(d)
    lable.append(l)
```